# Import .tif file in SAGA GIS

Tags: saga

While importing the .tif file through Geoprocessing -> File -> Grid -> Import ->Import Image, I am getting the following error in SAGA GIS 7.8.2.

```
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 34736 (0x87b0) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered (in module "TIFFReadDirectory")
12:27:37 PM: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples (in module "image")
12:27:37 PM: TIFF: Error reading image.
12:27:37 PM: Unknown image data format.
12:27:37 PM: Failed to load image from file "F:Basins\dem.tif".
```

Please help me solve this error message.

Comment: Where did this tif file come from? Can you post the results of GDALInfo? Your data loader should be ignoring tags it doesn't recognize but in the end it's saying that it's not a TIFF image that it can handle, it has 32 bit samples, but I don't see a problem Float32 is a valid format. Perhaps use GDAL_Translate to convert the TIFF to an IMG (-of hfa) if there are genuine problems in your tiff GDAL_Translate will have problems too, if not try to open the .img - this format does not support GeoTIFF tags so the problematic tags will be wiped.

Comment: I am trying to import an ALOS PALSAR DEM having 12.5m spatial resolution. The file type of the DEM is tif. I am able to open the same file in QGIS as well as ArcGIS. However, I am unable to import that in SAGA.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the new SAGA update and the problem was resolved.